# Weren't lmgtfy.com links blocked?

Tags: bug, status-completed

https://serverfault.com/questions/321559/how-to-install-a-vnc-server-on-ubuntu/321561#321561

In case of modify or delete, the full text of the answer is as follows:

```
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=vnc+ubuntu+installation
```

How'd that happen?  Aren't `lmgtfy.com` links blocked?

([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links))

[image: Errant answer]

Comment: I don't see that answer... maybe it's only available to 10k?

Comment: Feel free to flag those as Offensive. The -100 rep ding for an offensive-deleted answer should act as an incentive against using such links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added to the blacklist.

Answer (score 4):

According to [balpha](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/14041/balpha) they never were; though a whole slew of people disagree. Testing confirms they are not blocked at any level I can think of as of this edit.

This should be changed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with that. The reason is simply that `lmgtfy` is not blocked on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Just for some context, the lmgtgy blacklist was applied on a per site basis. I enquiried with the team about this, and up to now it had not been applied to SF. Now it has.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=serverfault%20blocked%20lmfgtfy) could help. ;-)